# Валидация в Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Использую классы .ng-valid .ng-invalid на input'ах, данные обновляются без перезагрузки страницы, поэтому когда поля очищаются, соответственно класс invalid остается, как это убрать?

[image: Вот до и после отправки формы]

Пример кода:

```
$scope.register = function () {
    $http.post('/addData', angular.toJson($scope.user)).success(function () {
        loadData();
        $scope.user = {};
    });
};
```

> $scope.user = {}; удаляет данные из формы

Вот jade код:

```
input#firstName(name='first_name' type='text' ng-model='user.first_name' required)
                input#lastName(name='last_name' type='text' ng-model='user.last_name' required)
                input#phone(name='phone' type='tel' ng-model='user.phone' required)
                input#male(name='male' value='male' type='radio' ng-model='user.gender' ng-required="!user.gender")
                input#female(name='female' value='female' type='radio' ng-model='user.gender' ng-required="!user.gender")
                input#age(name='age' type='number' ng-model='user.age' required)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все оказалось просто:

```
$scope.tableForm.$setPristine();
$scope.tableForm.$setUntouched();
```

Нужно было просто вызвать эти методы!